# How do you get values from models?

Tags: php, cakephp

After loading a model I the only way to get to the data seems to be very ugly.

```
$this->User->read(NULL, 49);
print $this->User->data['User']['email'];
```

Most frameworks have a much nicer way of accessing like

```
$User = new Model_User(49);
print $User->email;
```

Is there anyway to do this in CakePHP 1.2/3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a more type safe way to do it, unfortunately not. All model access is based on array structures and is one of the very things that frustrated me about Cake.

Comment: Bummer. I noticed it also forces all related structures to be loaded at once instead of using lazy loading for model relations...

Comment: @Xeoncross: It sounds like this would be unchangeable behavior, which is plain and simply wrong. A developer definitly has control over the associated data fetched. fyi bindModel, unbindModel, containable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The normal case is when you assign the result from this->read to a variable i.e.:

```
$user = $this->User->read(NULL, 49);
print $user['User']['email'];
```

Comment: In addition to my comment - the returned data could contain also the closest relations of the user's model. I.e. $user['Profile'] or $user['Activty'] etc.